# Visual proof for $f_{n+1}^2+f_n^2=f_{2n+1}$

Tags: calculus, alternative-proof, fibonacci-numbers

Suppose $f_n$ is fibonacci sequence $$f_1=1,f_2=1, f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_n$$ 
I see many visual proof for fibonacci formulas .
Is there a visuall proof for $$f_{n+1}^2+f_n^2=f_{2n+1}$$

Comment: You should give an example what you mean with "visual proof", just one of those many you know. For me, all proofs are visual, because I can see the words and formulas.

Comment: Probably something like this: https://mathoverflow.net/a/12024

Answer (score 0):

Easy to show that $$f_{n+1}f_{n+2}-f_{n-1}f_{n}=f_{2n+1}$$